# run javascript on popup html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a php page named **main.php** with a dropdown list on it. In dropdown list, there is an option '**Add new**'.
When user select **Add new** option, another php page named **popup.php** open in current pate i.e. main.php as a dialog box.
poputp.php has input forms. on click of button save, it must execute a javascript. But I dont know why javascript is not running.

**main.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <select id="data" name="data" on;>
        <option value="1">Code Project</option>
        <option value="2">Stack Overflow</option>
        <option value="new">Add New</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    function popup(val, arg){
        if(val.value == "new"){
            var url = 'popup.php';
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load(url)
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'title',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300
                });
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**popup.php**

```
<input type="text" name="value" id="value"/>
<input type="button" id="add" />

<script>
    $('#add').click(function (){
      alert($('value').val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for it ?

Comment: try to use .on("click")

Comment: Make sure it's in document ready.... or in order that you posted in popup.php

Comment: when popup.php is open as dialog box in main.php
no javascript of popup.php is loaded in browser

Answer (score 0):

use onchange="popup();"

```
<div class="row">
<select id="data" name="data" onchange="popup();">
    <option value="1">Code Project</option>
    <option value="2">Stack Overflow</option>
    <option value="new">Add New</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>


function popup(){
    var val = document.getElementById("data").value;
    if(val == "new") {
       prompt("execute your code here when condition met");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you please provide the complete source code or fiddle?